# Change Include Database In Project Setting After Creating Dataset

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset, mdf

When you create a dataset, you get the option of including the database file in your project, instead of the connection string pointing to the database file in the sql server data folder. My question is, is you select no, how can you later, after creating the dataset, change your mind and change, that the database file should be included in your project, and should be included in the release folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same option as you would to include any other existing item in your project.

You can then change the connection string in the Settings for the project, but I'm not sure whether that will work at design time or only run time.  You can easily enough just delete the `DataSet` and regenerate the Data Source.

The data file will be included in the output folder by default, but you should change the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy If Newer` unless you want to lose any changes you made during testing each time you build.

Comment: The problem is I have added a lot of custom queries to the table adapters. So starting from new doesn't work for me. The crux of my question is on how to change this particular setting after dataset is created

Comment: I just performed a test and what I said stands except for exactly how you go about changing the connection string.  I tried editing it vis the Settings UI and it didn't work.  I then did a Find In Files for the original data file path and edited each instance directly.  There were two in the settings file and one in the config file.  I just replaced the folder path with "|DataDirectory|", e.g. "C:\MyFolder\MyFile.mdf" became "|DataDirectory|\MyFile.mdf". You can then re-run the wizard on your existing data source in the Data Sources window.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried with the application settings UI and it worked. please rephrase the answer as follows: To change the above, there is a 2 step process, first you have to include the database in your project by using the "add exiting" method, the system then prompts you to make a new dataset, do it just to get it right. Then change the connection string in your original dataset with "|DataDirectory|", e.g. "C:\MyFolder\MyFile.mdf" becomes "|DataDirectory|\MyFile.mdf". Then you can delete the new dataset and keep the old. 
I will mark your answer as answered. Thanks